# cant initilize custom class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i have created a class that will hold user and device info. the class called `Account`.
here is the class code (ARC project) :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Account : NSObject
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *deviceID;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *accountID;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *oAuthCode;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *type;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *deviceToken;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *os;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *deviceName;
@end



#import "Account.h"

@implementation Account

 @synthesize deviceID = _deviceID;
 @synthesize deviceName = _deviceName;
 @synthesize deviceToken = _deviceToken;
 @synthesize type = _type;
 @synthesize oAuthCode = _oAuthCode;
 @synthesize accountID = _accountID;
 @synthesize os = _os;



 -(NSString*)deviceID{
     return [ThinkerBell_OpenUDID value];
 }

 -(NSString*)deviceToken{
     return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:K_DEVICE_TOKEN];
 }

 -(NSString*)os{
     return [[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion];
 }

 -(NSString*)deviceName{
     return [[UIDevice currentDevice]model];
 }
 @end
```

here i am creating an instance and trying to access his properties:

```
 _ac = [[Account alloc]init];
_ac.accountID = @"rf@gmmail.com";
_ac.type = @"rf@gmmail.com";
_ac.oAuthCode = @"rf@gmmail.com";
_ac.deviceName = @"rf@gmmail.com";
_ac.deviceToken = @"rf@gmmail.com";
_ac.deviceID = @"rf@gmmail.com";
_ac.os = @"rf@gmmail.com";
```

than i am passing this object as a parameter on a method :

```
    [self appendAccount:_ac];
```

when i am trying to read the `Account` instance his fields are .

```
 -(void)appendAccount:(Account*)account{
     NSLog(@"%@",account);
 }
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Please clarify what you think this code does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't implemented a "description" method in your class, so NSLog has nothing it can print out.

Here's how you could do it:

```
@implementation Account

- (NSString *)description
{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Account ID %@>", self.accountID];
}

@end
```

Also, delete these lines of code, they are usually not needed and can cause problems:

```
 @synthesize deviceID = _deviceID;
 @synthesize deviceName = _deviceName;
 @synthesize deviceToken = _deviceToken;
 @synthesize type = _type;
 @synthesize oAuthCode = _oAuthCode;
 @synthesize accountID = _accountID;
 @synthesize os = _os;
```

(you probably got that from old example code, I suggest finding something more recent and up to date)

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have no setters to reflect the getters. The value is written to _deviceid, but read from thinkerbell...

Comment: so i must write setters as well for every getter?

Comment: @orazran no, you should rarely need to write a getter or setter.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert, if topic starter writes his own getters that return values that do not reflect the synthesized getters, calling a setter to write to the _var is absolutely useless.

Comment: @RobvanderVeer I know, but he asked if he needed to write getters/setters manually. I was just answering that question.